# Encoded characters with XML builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, encoding, recursion

I'm writing my own to_xml method in rails for a specific model.
However, when my method is called recursively, the to_xml method
is encoding the result to special entities.

this is my method :

```
  def to_xml(options = {})
    require 'builder'
    options[:indent] ||= 2
    xml = options[:builder] ||= ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent => options[:indent] )
    xml.instruct! unless options[:skip_instruct]
    xml.node {
      if self.nodeparent
        xml.layout( self.nodeparent.to_xml(:skip_instruct=>true,:indent=>2) )
      end
      xml.package{
        self.package('Node').each do |node|
        end
      }
      xml.template{
        xml.name(self.template.name )
        xml.file(self.template.file )
      }
    }
  end
```

The "xml.layout" part is calling the to_xml method again on another instance of the same model. However the result source code is not valid XML, but an encoded string. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
  <layout>&lt;node&gt;
  &lt;package&gt;
  &lt;/package&gt;
  &lt;template&gt;
    &lt;name&gt;mainlayout&lt;/name&gt;
    &lt;file&gt;mainlayout&lt;/file&gt;
  &lt;/template&gt;
&lt;/node&gt;
</layout>
  <package>
  </package>
  <template>
    <name>homepage</name>
    <file>homepage</file>
  </template>
</node>
```

Is there any way to solve this? Should I use Nokogiri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nokogiri is the popular choice for all sorts of XML wrangling but builder can do what you want it to.

Builder assumes by default that any string you give to it is content that needs to be escaped. If that's not so, the you can use `<<` to append the XML directly, ie

```
xml.layout { xml << " some raw content" }
```

Comment: just tested it and it seems to work. However, I've also figured out another solution, using nokogiri. CGI.unescapeHTML(builder.to_xml)

Comment: That would also unescape anything that should be escaped though.

Comment: I'm using CDATA in those XML tags that could contain code... But you're right that this isn't optimal